# Dynamic use of AnkoComponent<*>.startActivity()

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, start-activity, anko

Is there a way to call startActivity() dynamically?

The purpose would be to have something like the following:

```
fun <T: Activity> buttonGoTo(): android.widget.Button {

    return button() {
        // do stuff
        onClick {startActivity<T>()}
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can start new activity through a new `Intent` object. Check Android docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`startActivity`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/doc/ADVANCED.md) method you're trying to use has a signature like:

`inline fun <reified T: Activity> Fragment.startActivity(vararg params: Pair<String, Any>)`

As you can see it uses [reified types parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). The consequence is that if you want to wrap the function in another helper function it has to be too inlined and use reified type parameters. What's even more important is that it requires nested functions/lambdas to use inlining too - which in case of `onClick` is not true.

However I think you can still achieve your goal with `intentFor<T>` like so:

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.buttonGoTo() = UI {
    val target = intentFor<T>()
    button() {
        onClick {
            startActivity(target)
        }
    }
}.view
```